# Special modules over symmetric algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric connected finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$.
Call a tuple of two modules $(X,M)$ (having no projective direct summands) cute in case $Ext^l(X,M) \neq 0$ for some $l \geq 1$ but $Ext^{l+i}(X,M)=0$ for all $i \geq 1$. We can assume that $M$ is indecomposable always.

Questions:

1. Is there an easy construction of cute tuples?
2. Are there cute tuples when the field is finite (or any other field that constists only of roots of unity)?